# Not able to open .pdf file in IE8

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf

I've posted this question in asp.net web forum but no one replied.

I can't open "ONE" page of .pdf file using IE8 and give me an error message "**the file is damaged and could not be repaired**" when retrieved from SQL Server 2008, but more than one page I can open with no problem.

With Chrome I can open any number of .pdf pages.

The same page that I can't open using IE8 from DB, can be opened directly from hard disk using IE8.

My code in .asxh file:

```
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf" 
    Dim strm As Stream = ShowNewsImage(imgName) 
    If Not strm Is Nothing Then 
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(4095) {} 
        Dim byteSeq As Integer = strm.Read(Buffer, 0, 4096) 

        Do While byteSeq > 0 
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq) 
            byteSeq = strm.Read(Buffer, 0, 4096) 
        Loop 
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer) 
    End If
```

Thanks,

Ahmed.

Comment: Any reason for writing the file in chunks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proble solved.

I changed the buffer from Object to Byte and it worked !!!

The old code (part of a handler) :

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Dim strm As Stream = ShowNewsImage(imgName)
    If Not strm Is Nothing Then
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(4095) {}
        Dim byteSeq As Integer = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096)

        Do While byteSeq > 0
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq)
            byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096)
        Loop
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer)
        context.Response.End()
    End If
End Sub

Public Function ShowNewsImage(ByVal imgName As String) As Stream
    Dim conn As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Connection").ConnectionString
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(conn)
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT image FROM Table WHERE ID = @ID"
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", imgName)
    connection.Open()
    Dim img As <strong>Object </strong>= cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    Try
        Return New MemoryStream(CType(img, Byte()))
    Catch
        Return Nothing
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try
End Function
```

As you see, ExecuteScalar() attached the output to an Object.
I changed this to Byte:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(4095) {}
    Dim byteSeq As Integer = 0
    Dim conn As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Connection").ConnectionString
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(conn)
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT image FROM Table WHERE ID = @ID"
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", imgName)
    connection.Open()

    buffer = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

    context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer)
    context.Response.End()
```

No need to context.Response.OutputStream.Write , it is already impeded in context.Response.BinaryWrite

Took me two days.

Answer (score 0):

Set Response.buffer to true and response.flush after finishing the PDF.

Comment: Thanks VSU, I tried it but gave me corrupted file and a message "the file is damaged and could not be repaired"

Answer (score 0):

Seems too obvious but I have to ask... did you try this?

```
Response.WriteFile(imgName)
```

[Link to documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile.aspx) in case you're not familiar with this. :)

Comment: Thanks Shadow Wizard for your reply